# System recycle bin location

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to know how I can find  the **path** of the recycle bin and its files.  I have tried  to find  them from a DOS command.  However, it took me to the `recycle.bin` but did not show its path.

How can I find out the path of recycle bin? Is there a command to retreive that?

Answer (score 4):

If you unhide System Files in Folder Options you can see the folder on the root of the System Drive which is usually C:

Windows Vista to Windows 10

C:$Recycle.bin

Windows 2000, XP, NT

C:RECYCLER

Windows 98 and earlier that used FAT file systems

C:RECYCLED

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_(computing)#Microsoft_Windows)

If you dual boot or multi boot any of these OS's you will multiple versions of the recycle bin folder on each drive.

Comment: I have windows 8.1. The directories c:recycler, c:recycled and the variable c:$recycle.bin do not exist. I suppose this is the case for windows 8 and 10 as well. Alternatives?